# Ionic account can not login when I run $ionic cordova resources android

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I want to change ionic project's icon and splash,so i run $ionic cordova resources android,and it need ionic account,so i did a signup,But i am geting an error which says:

**No user found by that email**.

Can you help me? I am looking forward for your reply.

[image]

cli packages: (C:\Users\c\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.10.3
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: I have created a ionic account,it says that this account no exsit.

Comment: cli packages: (C:\Users\c\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v6.10.3
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10

Comment: Can you read this? Please put that on your original post with `code` formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

According to your `ionic info`, you're using very old `app-scripts` and `ionic` version.So you need to upgrade it to latest to work with latest Ionic `CLI`.

You're `package.json` file should be [**like this**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json).

**Old Answer:**

Firstly you need to create a [**Free or dev account here**](https://dashboard.ionicjs.com/login).

After that you can use below CLI:

```
ionic cordova resources android
```

Here you can see how to [**Automating Icons and Splash Screens**](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/). But use latest `CLI`. This article has been used `old CLI`.

Comment: Em,i have created a ionic account.Then i create another new one,it says the same.

Comment: You don't need 2 A/Cs. Just create a one and see that.

Comment: My mother language is not English,perhaps you don't understand what i said.I means i already have an account, but it says my account is not exist.Why?It is strange.

Comment: Did you logged in? use `ionic login`

Comment: Can you log in by using dash board?

Comment: Can log in the dash board.

Comment: Can you show the `ionic info` details? Put it in your post above.

Comment: OK,you can see.

Comment: Sorry,like this?

Comment: Please see the **Update** on my post above.

Comment: So sorry,i am fool and i use stack overflow just one day.I cannot find the post,can you give me a link?